# Is there a light version of Python that only runs .pyc files?

Tags: python, embed, bytecode

I have files containing compiled Python bytecode. I want to run them through my executable program without the massive overload of the Python interpreter.

Any ideas?

Comment: You wouldn't save anything due to functions like `eval` or `compile`. And you still need an interpreter to run bytecode anyway, the only part not needed is the parser.

Answer (score 2):

pyc are not compiled to machine code. Use Shedskin for that.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the massive overhead of the interpreter: do you have any evidence that the compilation step is massive overhead?  You might be misunderstanding what is in a .pyc file.  Python bytecode is not machine code, it is very high-level bytecodes that are executed by the Python interpreter.

In any case, no, there is not a build of Python that can run .pyc files and not .py files.

Comment: I was talking about the executable size overhead - the python parser is a few megabytes, and I want to avoid that. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: How are you determining that the parser is a few megabytes?  My Python executable is 2.8Mb.  Are you calling the Python executable a "parser"?  It's much more than the parser, and it's essential for executing Python programs.

Comment: I find it hard to believe it's impossible to take out the part that compiles `.py` to `.pyc`, while still being able to run the .pyc (albeit without the `eval`/`compile` functions)

Comment: @Dor: you're still assuming that it would be an interesting amount of the interpreter to remove.  Let's say it's 25% of the interpreter, which is a high estimate.  So you've reduced it from 2.8Mb to 2.1Mb.  What have you gained?  What's the point?

Comment: You could attempt to run UPX on the executable: not sure if Python gets compressed when released.